# SQL query to find most prevalent associated value in table

Tags: sql

I have an simple SQL table that associates two values which looks like this:

```
table1(column1 varchar (32), column2 varchar(32));
```

For each distinct value in column1, out of the list of value it has, I want to find the one that occurs the most in this table.

An example to clarify:

let's say I have the following values:

```
a1, b1
a2, b2
a3, b3
a4, b1
a3, b1
a3, b2
a5, b1
a6, b2
```

the result I hope for is:

```
a1, b1
a2, b2
a3, b1
a4, b1
a5, b1
a6, b2
```

because `b1` and `b2` have the most occurrences in the table.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using HSQL at the moment, but I don't mind switching to anything that can be as portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good application for window functions.  There is more than one way to approach it.  Here is one method.  Get the frequency of `column2` on each row.  Then, rank all these frequencies using `row_number()`:

```
select column1, column2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by col2cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by column2) as col2cnt
            from t 
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

The final step (done by the outermost query) is to choose one with the highest rank (that is with the highest count).

In the event of ties (that is if `b2` appeared as often as `b1`), then this version would choose an arbitrary value.

Comment: I will have to study "partition by" and the star operator as it's being used here.

This wasn't in our "SQL for dummies" course :-) I'll report back with my findings.

Can't approve of this right now but it seems like you know your way around...